# Titanium isn't posting values to ColdFusion

Tags: post, coldfusion, titanium

This is my Titanium code:

```
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e){
        // just displays the response
        var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({html:this.responseText});
        win.add(webview);
    }
});

loginReq.open("POST",url);
var params = {
    email: email.value,
    passowrd: password.value
};

loginReq.send(params); // this is sending nothing according to a CF variable dump
```

The ColdFusion page just dumps all the variables, and it shows up on the iPhone emulator. But it's giving me an empty struct for the variables, which means no variables are actually getting sent in.

## How do I fix my Titanium code to actually post data?

Comment: As far as i can tell everything looks correct per the documentation. How are you dumping the variables?

Comment: What does console.log(params) give you when it fails?

Comment: [@KevinB](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) I was dumping VARIABLES. After reading your comment below I looked into dumping all scopes, and realized VARIABLES doesn't actually dump ALL the variables, and that was my issue! Side Question: How do you dump all variables? I tried getPageContext().getBuiltInScopes(), but I get a "the getbuiltinscopes method was not found" error.

Comment: I'm not sure, i usually dump them individually. variables, form, url, cgi, server, application, request, session, cookie are the primary ones

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send post data to a script you will have to to set the header accordingly:

```
loginReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

If you are sending JSON data to an API, you might need to stringify your parameters to send them:

```
loginReq.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

**Edit:**
According to the docs this is done automatically (see comments). In some of my network clients I had to do that explicitly, though...

Moreover, you might also want to implement the `onerror` callback, so in case your call fails for any reason you will know why:

```
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e){
        // just displays the response
        var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({html:this.responseText});
        win.add(webview);
    },

    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug('Status: ' + this.status);
        Ti.API.debug('Response: ' + this.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: not according to the documentation for Titanium, but what do i know, i don't use titanium. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle

Comment: True, the documentation says otherwise, but I have to use it with some of my network clients in order to get it working. To be honest: I don't know why this is the case, I would love to have a proper explanation ;) Anybody?

Comment: Placing a json string there isn't wrong, it just doesn't result in form params on the server. Since we don't know what exactly the OP means by *"The ColdFusion page just dumps all the variables"* we don't know how he's accessing the posted data. I'd assume he's listing the variables scope which wouldn't list the POST and GET scopes anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, according to the docs "The HTTPClient's send() method automatically stringifies data for you".
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_JSON_Data-section-29004905_WorkingwithJSONData-SendingJSONdata

Comment: [@KevinB](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) I was dumping variables. YOU WERE RIGHT! I thought variables dumped all the variables, it did not dump FORM though! WTF?! What a freaking noob (I've been developing in CF for about 10 years)! Thanks for the idea. So should I just delete this question? It ended up working without setRequestHeader, with what I originally posted.